# How to click a specific button on a window with autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

The button I want to click is on a not maximized on top window. It's like a tiny window on top of everything else. I want to address a hotkey to its button, for example pressing `D` and the button is pressed.

Comment: See [**ControlClick**](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlClick.htm) in the manual.

Answer (score 7):

See the AutoHotkey documentation as suggested by @user3419297
https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlClick.htm

With the window spy, you'll be able to find the control's Name/ID. For example, `Button2` or `Edit1`. Then use `ControlClick` on that control.

```
ControlClick, Button2, WindowTitle
```

Most likely you'll be able to use the button's text too. For example, an "OK" button.

```
ControlClick, OK, WindowTitle
```

In both examples given, WindowTitle is where you can put the words that show up in a window's title bar. More can be learned from the documentation.

Comment: X-Mouse Button Control works great for me

Answer (score 1):

If the button is not accessible by ControlClick you can try to do an ImageSearch or FindText https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=17834

Also have a look at the [UIAutomation Library](https://github.com/Descolada/UIAutomation)